# Change contenttype of all site collection libraries with Powershell

Tags: powershell-script

Change contenttype of all site collection libraries with Powershell

Hello everyone. I am an apprentice of powershell and SharePoint and I came across the following scenario:

I have a collection of sites http: // sites, with subsites and inside them I have libraries with documents that have as ContentType values: "Value1", "Value2", "Value3". I need to go through **all the libraries** in this collection and change the ContentTypes from "Value1" and "Value3" to "NewCT" from all files. Sweeping the web I came across a script that does this update but for a specific list and for just a specific term. I need help adjusting this script. Appreciate

```
function Reset-SPFileContentType ($WebUrl, $ListName, $OldCTName, $NewCTName)
{
#Get web, list and content type objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
$list = $web.Lists[$ListName]
$oldCT = $list.ContentTypes[$OldCTName]
$newCT = $list.ContentTypes[$NewCTName]
$newCTID = $newCT.ID

#Check if the values specified for the content types actually exist on the list
if (($oldCT -ne $null) -and ($newCT -ne $null))
{
    #Go through each item in the list
    $list.Items | ForEach-Object {
        #Check if the item content type currently equals the old content type specified
        if ($_.ContentType.Name -eq $oldCT.Name)
        {
            #Check the check out status of the file
            if ($_.File.CheckOutType -eq "None")
            {
                #Change the content type association for the item
                $_.File.CheckOut()
                write-host "Resetting content type for file" $_.Name "from" $oldCT.Name "to" $newCT.Name
                $_["ContentTypeId"] = $newCTID
                $_.Update()
                $_.File.CheckIn("Content type changed to " + $newCT.Name, 1)
            }
            else
            {
                write-host "File" $_.Name "is checked out to" $_.File.CheckedOutByUser.ToString() "and cannot be modified"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "File" $_.Name "is associated with the content type" $_.ContentType.Name "and shall not be modified"
        }
    }
}
else
{
    write-host "One of the content types specified has not been attached to the list"$list.Title
}
$web.Dispose()
}
Reset-SPFileContentType –WebUrl <Site URL> –ListName <Document library display name> –OldCTName <Content type to be replaced> –NewCTName <Content type to replace it with>
```

Referência: [source](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/change-content-type-set-on-files-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change those

```
$oldCT1 = $list.ContentTypes[$Value1]
$oldCT2 = $list.ContentTypes[$Value2]
```

And then change your if statement to check for both values.

```
if ($_.ContentType.Name -eq $oldCT1.Name -Or $_.ContentType.Name -eq $oldCT2.Name)
```

You can find more info on the if statemetn here: https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/if-and/